# How do I send a transaction to a smart contract?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, raw-transaction

I need to build this transaction and send it to the blockchain how do I do it ? 
I always used ethsendrawTransaction just to send eth but never I never built this type of transaction:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "from": "0x03733d509f60a33f1b86856560256351f23e5531",
      "to": "0xb626a5facc4de1c813f5293ec3be31979f1d1c78",
      "data": "0xf0843ba90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007000000000000000000000000c0829421c1d260bd3cb3e0f06cfe2d52db2ce3150000000000000000000000001f573d6fb3f13d689ff844b4ce37794d79a7ff1c0000000000000000000000001f573d6fb3f13d689ff844b4ce37794d79a7ff1c000000000000000000000000d7eb9db184da9f099b84e2f86b1da1fe6b305b3d000000000000000000000000d7eb9db184da9f099b84e2f86b1da1fe6b305b3d000000000000000000000000d7eb9db184da9f099b84e2f86b1da1fe6b305b3d0000000000000000000000006810e776880c02933d47db1b9fc05908e5386b96",
      "value": "0x16345785d8a0000",
      "gasPrice": "0x77359400",
      "nonce": "0x1c6",
      "gasLimit": "0x9dc62"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use web3.js.

Comment: I am using python but when I send the transaction it fails

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid transaction object. You should probably send `obj["data"][0]` (instead of `obj`).